# Do not cache dynamic content in CakePHP views

Tags: php, cakephp, caching

I'm trying to cache the views with the Cache helper. It works well for static content or for session content using `<!--nocache-->{...}<!--/nocache-->` but it's not working for internal action variables.

For exemple, if I have a cachable article and an not cachable user defined rating for this article, I can't use `<!--nocache-->echo $rating;<!--/nocache-->` to display this rating, because the rating variable will also be cached.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is intended behaviour.

Once an action is cached, all of the view variables are serialized and the action is not called again (until the cache is cleared etc).

Either: don't use view-caching, or set the cache time to expire more frequently.

If you want the rating to increase in "real time", then have your app clear the cache every time someone modifies the rating.

Your app will benefit from a cached version at least some of the time.

Comment: @Ross: No, I want to use the view cache but I want some variables to be computed each time. In fact, the solutions you propose is not working. As I said, this is a user defined rating, so if I cache it will be the same for each users instead of being user dependant. For ex., if UserA set a rating of 8/10, it's cached and even if UserB set 4/10 he see 8/10...

Comment: Once an action is cached, the logic for that action does NOT get called again. Whatever the variables are at the time of caching will be output. An alternative option would be to retrieve the most current "rating" via ajax and update that part once the cached page has loaded.

Comment: It's unique, that's why that variable is the only one that can not be cached. I'm prety sure that can be done as it's frequent. For exemple, on an online store, the pages have to be cached but it also contain a user cart that can't be cached...

Comment: you need to create a unique cache for each user then, or  use ajax to update whatever parts you need to be "uncached".

Comment: Unique cache for each user is quite useless as it's the same behavior as the browser cache and ajax solution seems to me complex and unappropriate. As an exemple, at Facebook they have to cache their Pages (no way they don't) but there is some user related info (like friends who like the page) and they don't use ajax to fetch these info !