# Should I be caching views for an e-commerce site with basket logic using CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, caching

For my e-commerce site the dynamic *page element basket* is available throughout the site.

I have been reading up on the [CakePHP CacheHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/cache.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045143/do-not-cache-dynamic-content-in-cakephp-views) treating a similar topic but for me it is not entirely clear if I should or can use the CacheHelper for my site (given this site-wide basket). I am hoping someone can clarify this statement for me:

The shopping basket is only updated using AJAX **at the product view page** (I want to cache this page) or **the full basket view page** (I don't want to cache this page). The AJAX basket update action **is different** from the product view action. The *page element basket count* is (as previously mentioned) available throughout the site and also one extra basket product specific element on the product view page. Since I am using the SessionHelper for the basket count site-wide, wrapping the *page elements basket* count with `<!--nocache--> <!--/nocache-->` would make it possible to cache pretty much all pages given the actions/views updating the basket wouldn't be cached. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got this right your approach should be ok.

You might want to checkout my [Cart plugin](https://github.com/burzum/Cart) as well instead of reinventing the wheel. ;)

Comment: Yeah, this approach seems to have worked. But I found that the view cache is cleared whenever the model changes, **in any action for that controller**. I didn't think about that initially, but since I am updating the model in pretty much every action for that controller, the view cache was cleared all the time, which sort of beats the purpose.